# Purchase Proccessed with Fatal Error : Maximum Execution Time Exceeded

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, php-5.4, fatal-error

After a customer hits submit order, the order gets processed & confirmation email goes out.. However, the page never loads and a `PHP Fatal Error: Maximum Execution time` occurs. We have increased the `max_execution_limit` from 30 to 60 to 90 seconds and it's still happening. We also have plenty of system resources available.

Outside customers telling us when they experience this. We can detect this happening because the order shows up in our Magento order history and doesn't in our Analytics (which requires a complete page load for the Javascript)

Below are the 5 errors logs from the past 24 hours.. All these errors coincide with the exact time an order was placed that wasn't picked up by our Javascript analytics:

```
[03-May-2015 15:46:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /lib/Zend/Locale.php on line 1637
[04-May-2015 03:57:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 636
[04-May-2015 04:00:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 997
[04-May-2015 14:03:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php on line 201
[04-May-2015 15:23:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 1306
[05-May-2015 23:52:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in /app/code/core/Zend/Date.php on line 1084
```

It's strange that it's not the same file creating the same error every time..

Comment: Does it happen all the time or it is kind of random behavior?

Comment: I estimate it happens around 10% of the time. Haven't figured out the pattern yet. Doesn't seem to be related to order size OR product type. I've seen it happen to orders with a single simple product.

Comment: Are any external systems integrated with your checkout experience? Something other than the shipping and payment methods, which would have already been invoked by the time the order is actually created. It's possible that an integration with an external system is timing out, because not much else happens in Magento between sending the confirmation email and redirecting to the confirmation page.

Comment: create a phpinfo page, see if the values you are changing are for the correct php.ini file.

Comment: @Agop, your insight into `"not much else happens between sending the confirmation email and redirecting to the confirmation page"` is a good start. Any suggestions on how to identify the final steps before the redirect to the confirmation page?? @sr_magento, we do have a phpinfo page and the values are set correctly.

Comment: The redirect happens via JS in `Review.prototype.nextStep()` in `opcheckout.js` if the AJAX response indicates success. `Review` is instantiated in `template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml`, where you'll see the AJAX action (`checkout/onepage/saveOrder`) and the success action (`checkout/onepage/success`). The `saveOrder` action calls `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder()`, which does most of the work (including sending the confirmation email). Long story short, not much happens between the email and the redirect. Check for modules with observers listening to checkout events.

Comment: Some example checkout events include `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` and `checkout_submit_all_after`. Perhaps there's a module that hooks into one of these events and triggers some additional logic. Alternatively, there may be a module that overrides some of Magento's core checkout logic directly.